# Apache Isis - Security Module Realm

Tags: security, isis

I am trying to configure the security of Apache Isis as "Security Module Realm", I did everything that comes in the documentation but I am getting the following error:

```
 631047 22:18:37,461  [IsisTransaction      qtp246168102-19 INFO ]  abort transaction IsisTransaction@42052069[state=IN_PROGRESS,commands=0]
    631052 22:18:37,466  [AbstractAuthenticator qtp246168102-19 WARN ]  Authentication failed for token submission [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - isis-module-security-admin,
    rememberMe=false].  Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException).
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing code in a temporary session
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory.doInSession(IsisSessionFactory.java:366)
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory.doInSession(IsisSessionFactory.java:344)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm.execute(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:221)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm.lookupPrincipal(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:138)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:76)
            at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568)
            at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180)
            at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267)
            at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
            at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
            at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
            at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
            at org.apache.isis.security.shiro.ShiroAuthenticatorOrAuthorizor.authenticate(ShiroAuthenticatorOrAuthorizor.java:151)
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.authentication.standard.AuthenticationManagerStandard.authenticate(AuthenticationManagerStandard.java:111)
            at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.viewer.integration.wicket.AuthenticatedWebSessionForIsis.authenticate(AuthenticatedWebSessionForIsis.java:73)
            at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.AuthenticatedWebSession.signIn(AuthenticatedWebSession.java:66)
            at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.panel.SignInPanel.signIn(SignInPanel.java:210)
            at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.panel.SignInPanel.access$100(SignInPanel.java:46)
            at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.panel.SignInPanel$SignInForm.onSubmit(SignInPanel.java:305)
            at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1316)
            at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
            at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.StatelessForm.process(StatelessForm.java:100)
            at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
            at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:708)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
            at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
            at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:241)
            at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
            at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
            at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
            at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
            at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
            at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
            at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
            at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
            at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
            at org.apache.isis.core.webapp.diagnostics.IsisLogOnExceptionFilter.doFilter(IsisLogOnExceptionFilter.java:52)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
            at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
            at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
            at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
            at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
            at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
            at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
            at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:306)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm$1.lookupUser(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:149)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm$1.execute(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:141)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm$1.execute(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:138)
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager.executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:188)
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager.executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:178)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm.doExecute(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:236)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm$3.call(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:227)
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory.doInSession(IsisSessionFactory.java:364)
            ... 73 more
    631069 22:18:37,483  [ShiroAuthenticatorOrAuthorizor qtp246168102-19 ERROR]  Unable to authenticate
    org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed for token submission [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - isis-module-security-admin, rememberMe=false].
    Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException).
            at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:214)
            at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
            at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
            at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
            at org.apache.isis.security.shiro.ShiroAuthenticatorOrAuthorizor.authenticate(ShiroAuthenticatorOrAuthorizor.java:151)
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.authentication.standard.AuthenticationManagerStandard.authenticate(AuthenticationManagerStandard.java:111)
            at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.viewer.integration.wicket.AuthenticatedWebSessionForIsis.authenticate(AuthenticatedWebSessionForIsis.java:73)
            at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.AuthenticatedWebSession.signIn(AuthenticatedWebSession.java:66)
            at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.panel.SignInPanel.signIn(SignInPanel.java:210)
            at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.panel.SignInPanel.access$100(SignInPanel.java:46)
            at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.panel.SignInPanel$SignInForm.onSubmit(SignInPanel.java:305)
            at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1316)
            at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
            at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.StatelessForm.process(StatelessForm.java:100)
            at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
            at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:708)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
            at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
            at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:241)
            at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
            at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
            at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
            at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
            at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
            at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
            at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
            at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
            at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
            at org.apache.isis.core.webapp.diagnostics.IsisLogOnExceptionFilter.doFilter(IsisLogOnExceptionFilter.java:52)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
            at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
            at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
            at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
            at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
            at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
            at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
            at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:306)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing code in a temporary session
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory.doInSession(IsisSessionFactory.java:366)
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory.doInSession(IsisSessionFactory.java:344)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm.execute(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:221)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm.lookupPrincipal(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:138)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:76)
            at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568)
            at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180)
            at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267)
            at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
            ... 65 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm$1.lookupUser(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:149)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm$1.execute(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:141)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm$1.execute(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:138)
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager.executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:188)
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.transaction.IsisTransactionManager.executeWithinTransaction(IsisTransactionManager.java:178)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm.doExecute(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:236)
            at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm$3.call(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:227)
            at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory.doInSession(IsisSessionFactory.java:364)
            ... 73 more
```

Could you explain what I need to do? Why do i get the error?
The error appears when logging into the wicket.
What I did was the following:

Shiro.ini

```
[main]
isisModuleSecurityRealm=org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm

authenticationStrategy=org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.AuthenticationStrategyForIsisModuleSecurityRealm
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authenticationStrategy

securityManager.realms = $isisModuleSecurityRealm
```

Isis.properties

```
isis.appManifest=domainapp.application.manifest.DomainAppAppManifest

isis.services-installer=configuration-and-annotation
isis.services.ServicesInstallerFromAnnotation.packagePrefix=org.isisaddons.module.security

isis.services = org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.password.PasswordEncryptionServiceUsingJBcrypt,\
        org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.permission.PermissionsEvaluationServiceAllowBeatsVeto

isis.reflector.facets.include=org.isisaddons.module.security.facets.TenantedAuthorizationFacetFactory

isis.reflector.facet.cssClassFa.patterns=\
                         new.*:fa-plus,\
                         add.*:fa-plus-square,\
                         create.*:fa-plus,\
                         update.*:fa-edit,\
                         remove.*:fa-minus-square,\
                         find.*:fa-search,\
                         all.*:fa-list
```

webapp/pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- this app -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>Onboarding-application</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- isis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.isis.mavendeps</groupId>
        <artifactId>isis-mavendeps-webapp</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Shiro Module Security-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.isisaddons.module.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>isis-module-security-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

(I see you raised this on our mailing list, so I've answered it there also: 
https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r3852139ee593820b2e3044452b8747c129692f6cb17ca8db79772a63%40%3Cusers.isis.apache.org%3E )

The root cause seems to be n one of our integration classes.
Apologies for that, it should fail more graciously.

From your stack trace I see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm
$1.lookupUser(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:149)
    at org.isisaddons.module.security
```

Could you put a break point at that point to see what the issue is. If you
want we could screen share to look at this together (contact via the mailing list).

Dan

Comment: applicationUserRepository is null.
I sent you a screenshot to the email.

Comment: responded on the mailing list - my guess is that the security module (SecurityModule) is not declared as a dependency in Module#getDependencies()

https://github.com/incodehq/incode-platform/blob/master/modules/spi/security/impl/src/main/java/org/isisaddons/module/security/SecurityModule.java